# ImportError: No module named app - Trying to run unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

So I have a folder structure like so.

```
└── myApp
    ├── app
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── core
    │   ├── db.py
    │   ├── schema.sql
    │   ├── static
    │   │   ├── fonts
    │   │   ├── images
    │   │   ├── js
    │   │   └── resources
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── tests
    │   │   └── tests.py
    │   ├── utils.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── con.py
    ├── config.py
    ├── manifest.json
    ├── run.py
    ├── deps
    ├── store
```

As you can see my tests.py is in the app/tests folder.

`app = Flask(__name__)` is declared within **init**.py but whenever i try to run my tests my folder (which I do from myApp directory like so: python app/tests/tests.py) I get a `ImportError: No module named app`.

I'm not sure if this information is relevant, to run the app I normally run run.py which has `app.run(debug = True, host='0.0.0.0')` inside of it.

Thanks.

tests.py:

```
import os
import unittest
from app import app

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.db_fd, app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
        self.app = app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.unlink(app.config['DATABASE'])

    def test_empty_db(self):
        rv = self.app.get('/index')
        assert b'No entries here so far' in rv.data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I don't want to import tests.py anywhere though. I want to run it on it's own. Edit: Whoever i was replying to deleted their comment.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible this is because the `tests.py` is inside the `app`? meaning python won't find the `app` because he isn't looking in directories above this one.

```
import os.path
import sys
newPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir, os.path.pardir))
sys.path.append(newPath)
from app import app
sys.path.remove(newPath)
del newPath
```

this is a very ugly way to add a path to where python looks for imports. This example goes 2 directories up, which should bring it to the `myApp` directory.

If this is the problem, you could also consider moving the `tests` directory to the `myApp` folder or some other location. But I am no expert on python packaging/app etiquette. Might consider looking that up

Answer (score 0):

You can look if the path to your module is already set by typing sys.path. If not, you have to set it, e.g. in the file with the unit tests with something like:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'app'))
```